# Where did the Google Admob Ads App Id go?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, ads

I'm updating my App to the new Google Ads Play Services API (19.3.0) following the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start) and I couldn't find information anywhere about where to put the Admob App Id (the one with the `~`).

Is the App Id deprecated? Does the Ad Unit Id suffice now (the one with the `/`)? What am I missing?

Did the call to `MobileAds.initialize(context)` also become unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest.

Call to MobileAds.initialize(context) is needed.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.smh">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_app_square"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_icon_app_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value=" **app id goes here** " />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: That looks like old news to me. Could you please back your answer up with a link to official documentation from Google?

Comment: Why dont you just try it out?

Comment: I have no doubt that 'it works'. But that is not what my question is about. The documentation from Google used to show exactly what you're suggesting. That has changed. My question is: Does the new documentation from Google mean that the App Id is no longer required?